# Connect progressbar to individual functions+tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've looked over the various other questions from other users and have not found exactly what I'm looking for, if perhaps I missed something let me know. I'm looking for a simple way to connect a progressbar to each function in my tkinter GUI. I'm new to python and so am still learning how to do basic things. I would like the progressbar to update in determinate mode whenever the user pushes a button, so they're aware the GUI is still working and know how much time is left to complete each task. So for example when they click on script1, how do I write the code for a progressbar that updates during the completion of that task? Here's my code below:

```
 from sys import exit
 from Tkinter import *
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 import os
 import time
 import sys
 import ttk

 Root = Tk()
 Root.title("PIER PROCESSING GUI")

 class Command:
     def __init__(self, func, *args, **kw):
         self.func = func
         self.args = args
         self.kw = kw
     def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
         args = self.args+args
         kw.update(self.kw)
         self.func(*args, **kw)

     def script1(Where):
         Cmd = "build_new_pier %s"%Where
         print "Cmd =", Cmd
         Sp = Popen(Cmd, shell = True, stderr = PIPE)
         Ret = Sp.stderr.read()
         if len(Ret) != 0:
             print Ret
         return
     def quitter():
        exit(0)

     Label(Root, text = "Push button to build a new PIER").pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)
     Sub = Frame(Root)
     Button(Sub, text = "build_new_pier WEST", command = Command(script1, \
     "WEST")).pack(side = LEFT, pady = 5)
     Button(Sub, text = "build_new_pier EAST", command = Command(script1, \
     "EAST")).pack(side = LEFT, pady = 5) 
     Button(Sub, text = "build_new_pier SOUTH", command = Command(script1, \
     "SOUTH")).pack(side = LEFT, pady = 5)

     Sub.pack(side = TOP)
     Button(Root, text = "Quit", command = quitter).pack(side = TOP, pady = 5)
     Root.geometry("700x500+500+500")
     Root.mainloop()
```

I only included the first script call as the other calls are virtually the same. Is it better to call the progressbar outside of the function, i.e., one that measures each function? Or should I have a progressbar connected to each individual function? Either way, how do I construct such a thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at these post : [Tkinter command ignores some lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458894/tkinter-command-ignores-some-lines/26459705#26459705) I provide an example of progress bar that move continuously during a certain time.

Adapted use case for you would probably be:

```
Create a thread
Call your shell command through "popen" in this thread
While waiting the thread end, make the progress bar moving !
Return the result and delete the progress bar.
```

I let you try this and update your question to provide updated attempt.
As I don't have any idea of which scrip I should call with popen I cannot do many more to help you, sorry. (Is the call to an external scrip really required?)

Good luck.

Arthur.